# Databricks notebook run from Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-databricks

I am trying to call Databricks api to run a notebook or job by its ID by the API endpoint `api/2.0/jobs/run-now` but I am getting an error like getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND  `https://adb-<workspace-id>.<random-number>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/run-now`. But I am giving the right url (NOTE: I copied the url from the browser address bar till .net as per the example mentioned in : [Example Job API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/examples)

Below is my Node.JS code :

```
router.get('/triggerJob', (req, res) => {
    var job_payload = {
        "job_id": <Job_ID>
    }

    var options = {
        host: 'https://adb-<workspaceid>.<number>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/run-now',
        body: JSON.stringify(job_payload),
        method: 'Post',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'token' }
    }
    var data = '';
    console.log('till here')
    var request = https.request(options, function (result) {
        var body = "";
        result.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('data came');
            body += data;
        });
        result.on('end', function () {
            console.log('ended too');
            data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
    request.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    request.end();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As I got Solution for my question I want share it with all for the future refernce.

According to microsoft docs: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#--run-now)

They ask us to hit the url with `https://adb-<workspaceid>.<number>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/run-now` but I got is we need to hit the url:

https://<{locationname}>.azuredatabricks.net then api/2.0/jobs/run-now. So below is the code for the same:

```
  const request=require("request");
  const rp=require("request-promise");
   
   const triggerJob=((res,req)=>{
        var job_payload = {
        "job_id": <Job_ID>
    }

 var options = {
        host: 'https://<locationname>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/run-now',
        body: JSON.stringify(job_payload),
        method: 'Post',
        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/jsoon','Authorization': 'Bearer token' }
    }
    var response=await rp(url,options);
    if(response!=null){
     return res.json(response)
   }
});

module.exports= triggerJob;
```

I minimize the line of code for clarity.